# Access Codeigniter functions from external script

Tags: php, codeigniter, background-process

So, here's my situation :

- I have a complete app set up with CodeIgniter.
- I'm initiating a **background task**, running a PHP script.

My question :

- How could I use CodeIgniter function (e.g. `$this->db` or `$CI->db` - doesn't matter) from that external PHP script?

---

*Idea :* Could a workaround, like `include 'index.php';` at the top of the script do the trick?

Comment: which functions you want to access?

Comment: @HappyApe Basically the `db` object, for now. (It wouldn't do any harm to be able to access anything though, but this will do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent Codeigniter versions you can [run standard controller actions from command line](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html).
If your task is some kind of a daemon you can embed the "task trigger" logic in a long running part of your script and shell out for the actual work to CI land.

Comment: Hmmm... this definitely sounds promising. I'll have a look into it. Thanks! :-)

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your suggestion, my friend! - it's *exactly* what I wanted (or wished for). **Brilliant answer!** Köszönöm!