# Call function codeigniter script by external script

Tags: php, codeigniter

**My situation is:**

- I have a project with codeigniter working
- Inside of controllers i need to call a function of a php script
- I have other script running background and when it get data, send to codeigniter controller

**code:**

first line:

```
include('/opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/application/controllers/myFile.php');
```

This script is running backgroud.

```
function procmsg($topic,$msg){
    //do something...
    //my_function() is a function in the myFile.php script
    my_function(true, $userGtwy, $passwdGtwy, $node_id, $idGateway, $value, $rssi);
}
```

myFile.php

First lines of this script:

```
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

The function:

```
public function my_function($flag=false, $usr, $pass, $node, $gateway, $val, $freq){}
```

When I run my first script i get:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant APPPATH - assumed 'APPPATH' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/application/controllers/myFile.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  require(APPPATH/libraries/REST_Controller.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/application/controllers/myFile.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'APPPATH/libraries/REST_Controller.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/application/controllers/myFile.php on line 3
```

and, if i comment this line:

```
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');
```

i get:
 `No direct script access allowed`
I need this library and I need access with my script, help me please!

I found this: [Access Codeigniter functions from external script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735455/access-codeigniter-functions-from-external-script) 
But i don't understand...

My question, can i do that? or is it impossible?

Comment: You can not load controllers with in controllers HMVC best for that. also your filename wrong should be controllers/Myfile.php same as class

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yeah sorry, my controller name its fine, only i put the wrong name in this example... So, i can not load the controller and much less the function? :/

Comment: Something is wrong with your `index.php` file. That is location where both constants are defined (`APPPATH` and `BASEPATH`).

Comment: @Tpojka thanks, but I'll send data by POST xD that not fix the problem but its an alternative... thanks everybody! :)